# MYSQL how to convert varchar to bigint

Tags: mysql

Mysql How to convert a column of the type varchar 2017-10-10 23:59:21.087 to bigint?

I want to convert the type '2017-10-10 23:59:21.087' to 20171010235921087

Comment: What have you tried? Can we see your current SQL that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('2017-10-10 23:59:21.087', '-', ''), ':', ''), ' ', '')
```

If it's a field in a table, just do this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(forex_lastupdate, '-', ''), ':', ''), ' ', '')
FROM noksek_tickdata_copy;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a column named forex_lastupdate in the table noksek_tickdata_copy. The type of the column is varchar same with '2017-10-10 23:59:21.087'. So, I want to convert this column to bigint like 20171010235921087.

Comment: Just replace the hardcoded date in my query with the field name.